# Performance with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I have another question about performance with EF.

There's one method to get an object from context:

```
tDocumentTyp DocumentTypObject = Context.tDocumentTyps.Where(s => s.DocumentTypID == iTypID).FirstOrDefault();
```

This method takes ~2979 ms.

Then I wrote a method to get the DBSet via reflection and is executed this way:

```
tDocumentTyp DocumentTypObject = Context.GetEntries<tDocumentTyp>().Where(s => s.DocumentTypID == iTypID).FirstOrDefault();
```

My method needs ~222 ms to execute.

So my question now is, why is my method much faster than the original one? Or is there anything wrong with my method?

To make this a bit easier, here is my method for getting DBSet via reflection:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetEntries<T>(this AppContext DataContext,
    string PropertyName = null, IEnumerable<string> includes = null) where T : IEntity
{
    Type ContextType = typeof(AppContext);
    PropertyInfo Entity = null;
    if (null == PropertyName)
        Entity = ContextType.GetProperty(typeof(T).Name) 
                    ?? ContextType.GetProperty(typeof(T).Name + "s");
    else
        Entity = ContextType.GetProperty(PropertyName);

    if (null == Entity)
        throw new Exception("Could not find the property. If the property is not equal to the tablesname, you have to parametrize it.");
    DbQuery<T> set = ((DbSet<T>)Entity.GetValue(DataContext, null));
    if (includes != null)
        includes.ForEach(f => set = set.Include(f));
    return set;
}
```

Comment: EF is an ORM. It generates and executes SQL statements. Where are the queries that were generated? Does the underlying table have indexes? Are you even getting the same results? How did you benchmark the code? Your method returns a query cast to an IEnumerable, which should *execute* the query.

Comment: Hey, yes, I'm getting the same results. I can change values via the context and save and all fine for now... there are no indices

Comment: No indices means that the server will have to search *all* rows to find a match. You still haven't posted the *SQL queries generated* though. You can't troubleshoot SQL performance if you don't know what gets executed and against what - how many rows are there? How do you connect to the database? How do you time the code? You could be reading cached values repeatedly for example, thinking that somehow the secod method is faster. Are you reusing the same context in the tests?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger are you perhaps benchmarking one after the other, the first running as a cold query while the context is already initialized for the second?

Answer (score 0):

The second example is getting the entire table and applying the `Where` in memory. You are applying the extension method `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where` which operates on `IEnumerable<T>`. Note that this is an in-memory implementation. In the first example you using the extension method `System.Linq.Queryable.Where` which operates on `IQueryable<T>`. This is a different method, though they share the same name.

If you inspect closely you will also find that in the first example the method parameter is of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` whilst in the second example it is simply `Func<T, bool>`. This is a very important difference: the expression can be processed to produce a SQL-query.

So why is the second one faster? Well, that is hard to answer without more information about your data source. But as others have noted in the comments, if the database is not indexed then it may well be quicker to select the entire table and execute the filter in memory than to have the SQL server apply the filtering.

Comment: It *doesn't* make sense for the second query to be faster, much less 10x. In both cases the server has to scan all rows. In case #1 though only 1 row would be returned. In the second, the entire table would be sent back. Perhaps, if the server's hardware is *very very* slow,  and the data set small, performing the calculation on the client is faster. More likely though is that the testing code is wrong and eg, uses cached values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Server does not need to "scan" all rows to return the entire table, not in the sense in which it needs to if there is a `where`. Selecting an entire table is an optimized operation on most server implementations. EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm not arguing against your point that it should probably not be faster :)  Simply pointing out that selecting an entire table can be optimized.

Comment: A table scan would be necessary in both cases - that's what happens when no index is used. In the first case though, the queyr is likely a `SELECT TOP 1 ... WHERE ...`. Only one row would be returned. In the second, all rows would. In fact, I'd bet the execution plans for both queries would show the second case requires a lot more IO. The OP though hasn't provided the queries, the execution plans, or even the data size. 10x simply isn't logical.

Comment: Actually it *could* happen if the entity is mapped to a *very* complex view on top of large tables instead of a table, resulting in a much more complex execution plan when the filter is present. This is all wild speculation though

Comment: thanks odyss-jii and @Panagiotis Kanavos, i will check later and update my question if i find out something.. There's no logging enabled in this project..